# Cleaning up excel column that has same data in different variations (typos from manually entering, etc.)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file with a column that is messy which contains the same information but in different variations due to entering them manually. I'll give an example, I can have a column with  application names entered differently (Google, google company, yahoo!, yahoo, Messenger, Facebook Messenger, etc.)> Basically I want to clean up the entire column so that the names appear in a consistent and fixed way only, I have tried the fuzzy look up features in tools like Kutools and all but it doesn't work 100% and it is still too manual especially if your column has over 30,000 rows to apply fixes to them.

Is there a more efficient way to clean up data? I am open to suggestions about other tools or even if a VBA solution can be applied.

I also have a separate excel file that has a good format of the information. Is it possible to somehow to do a fuzzy lookup between the two sources and at the same time replace the messy column data using the clean data column?

Example: Messy column (Google, google company, yahoo!, yahoo, Messenger, Facebook Messenger)

Clean column (Google, Yahoo!, Messenger)

Desired result: To do a comparison check between the two and replace the messy data using the clean one if the similarity is strong)

Comment: Welcome! No, unfortunately there is no way that will accomplish this task with 100% success - in any case, "fuzzy manual input" must be checked by "clear manual review". No algorithm will be able to clear the string **Google, Gogle, Goole, Gooogle, Golem, Googlem** - and manual input can give any of these options. My condolences, get ready to manually check and correct this column.

Comment: Of course, you can greatly facilitate this work for yourself if you split each string into separate words by commas, count the number of each of these words in a column and sort in ascending order - most likely only the first 20-30 rows will contain misspelled names - it remains to find them in the table and replace with unified ones.

Comment: One way to start is by using Power Queryr (available in Windows Excel 2010+), and execute a "fuzzyJoin" between your existing table and your "clean" table.  Adjust the "Threshold" until you seem to be close; then review manually.

Comment: Microsoft offers a Fuzzy Logic Lookup Add-In for Excel.  I have not used it, but have heard mostly positive reviews.  It's at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011  If at some future point the link doesn't work any more, just google "Microsoft Fuzzy Lookup."  Highly recommend a tutorial like https://youtu.be/IG27sqkIO8w if you are going to try it.  Will be hard to be successful without that.

Comment: Thank you all, i will try suggestions and update this post accordingly

Comment: To further scope your problem, use `unique` (or remove duplicates) to see how many different names you have in your messy column, if it becomes a managable number, then  a simple vlookup can be used.

Comment: Hi all, happy to say that i stumbled upon a python algorithm that really worked 100% accurately for my 30,000 rows surpisingly! Not only is it accurate but it is very fast in a matter of 2 seconds. I shall post the link to the github respository. The code comes in ray python or you can download the executable.  
   [link] https://github.com/probablyfine/matchapp#pre-built-executable